# Java infinitely recursive self referential types

Tags: java, generics, recursion, types

I'm trying to create an implementation of Map that takes collections as keys.

What do you even call this conundrum?

What is the right way to do the class signature?

```
class SubClass <K extends Collection<E>, V> implements Map<K, V>
```

^^ Is improper syntax, but indicates what I want to do.

```
class SubClass <K extends Collection<K>, V> implements Map<Collection<K>, V>
```

^^ Results in a SubClass for which you can never declare the generic type. K is infinitely recursive. It also doesn't describe the type of behavior I'm looking for.

```
class SubClass <K , V> implements Map<K, V>
```

^^ Doesn't enforce the constraint that K needs to be a Collection

```
class SubClass <K extends Collection, V> implements Map<K, V>
```

^^ Doesn't allow us to know the generic types of the Collection

```
class SubClass <E, K extends Collection<E>, V> implements Map<K, V>
```

^^ Works, but is rather unwieldy

Comment: My guess would be `class SubClass <E, K extends Collection<E>, V> implements Map<K, V>`, though that requires you to declare a third type parameter whenever you create a `SubClass` variable.

Comment: Please clarify _infinite recursive generic types_. That doesn't seem to apply here. Can you change your title?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis infinite recursive generic types because if you tried to define a generic <E extends Collection<E>> you could never actually declare it. You would have something like <Collection<Collection<Collection<Collection<...>>>>
Do you think I should change the title still?

Comment: That's not what that is. This is more commonly known as a [self referential type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206). For example, the method `Collections#sort` is defined like `static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort`, declared a self-referential type `T` with a `Comparable` bound that refers to itself. The type `Integer` is compatible with this bound since it is defined as `class Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`.

Comment: Recursive self referential types? Infinitely self referential types? Self referential types with collections?

What would you recommend for a title?

Comment: Just "self-referential types". (You can use @username to reply to someone.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis then what's the best way to differentiate between a self referential type which can be declared (such as E extends Comparable<E>) compared to ones which can not be declared (such as E extends Collection<E>)?

Comment: @kag0 Why do you think either of those is illegal? I can do `class Whatever implements Collection<Whatever> {...}`. I wouldn't, but I could.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis both will compile, so in that sense they are "legal". The one with Comparable is perfectly fine, the one with Collection makes it impossible to declare a variable of that class with generic type parameters. Maybe my example wasn't full enough. I don't mean `class Whatever implements Collection<Whatever>{...}` I mean `class Whatever <E extends Collection<E> implements Collection {...}`

Comment: I still don't understand. `class Whatever<E extends Collection<E>> implements Collection {...}` compiles just fine (which is similar to what I have in my answer except it self-references).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right, it compiles fine. But you could never declare a variable of that class with generic type parameters. For example you can't have `Whatever</fully declared generics/> myVar;` because you would need to elaborate `/fully declared generics/` infinitely. It would look like this `Whatever<List<List<List<List<...>>>>> myVar;`

I'm hoping you can tell me if there is a name for this particular type of self referential type (pending my ability to explain what this particular type of self referential type is)

Comment: @kag0 See edit to my answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yup, that does allow it to be declared, neat. Is there a name for that kind of thing?

Comment: I've never heard a name for it specifically. "self-referencing" is the closest you'll get, afaik.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need a type parameter for the `Collection` element type, potentially a type parameter for the actual `Collection` type if you need it, and a type parameter for the values.

```
class SubClass<E, K extends Collection<E>, V> implements Map<K, V> { ... }
```

If you don't need the specific `Collection` type, you can use

```
class SubClass<E, V> implements Map<Collection<E>, V> { ... }
```

---

Concerning the various comments on your question

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Whatever<Self> s = new Whatever<>();
    }
}

class Self extends ArrayList<Self> {
}

class Whatever<E extends Collection<E>> {
}
```